# RAM upgrade for HP Envy 17 fails to boot

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, ramdisk

My laptop is HP Envy 17 touchsmart model 17-j013cl. When I bought it, it had 2GB RAM installed. I needed to upgrade the RAM and bought another identical 2GB RAM. Now the laptop does not show me even the bios screen. When I remove any of the two chips, the laptop boots and works fine. Each of the chips I have now is with the following details:

**Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-10-zzz**

**M471B5773CHS-CK0**

can this problem be solved ?

Comment: What makes you believe your hardware supports 4 GB?

Comment: @Ramhound Probably the [specifications](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03770522).

Comment: The service manual is indicating to me that the Samsung memory should have never worked.  I can't find evidence it even has 2 DIMM(s).

Comment: @Ramhound Weird. I have two sources that suggest that this memory should be compatible.

Comment: The user guide indicated the machine has two DIMM(s) but the voltage on the Samsung modules are higher ( 1.5 v vs 1.35 v ) in the part from the service manual.  So i have no idea what to believe.

Answer (score 1):

Product **M471B5773CHS-CK0** is *1.35v* and **Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-10-zzz** is *1.5v*. That would explain your instability. **M471B5773CHS-CK0** is PC3L, which stands for *low voltage*.

You stated that with two sticks of either set works fine. If you try mixing one stick from each set, it should fail. To fix your problem, return your new set you just got and pick a stick from [here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007609%20600006178%20600000410%20600000406&IsNodeId=1)

I would recommend picking the GSkill, Kingston, and there is also a matching Samsung set in that link.

You can verify that this is the issue by looking on your RAM sticks. If one of the sets says PC3L an the other is PC3, that would prove that they are running different voltages.

Comment: I tried SK Hynix 8GB 2Rx8 PC3L 12800 not working so I got this one which is PC3 not PC3L in other words now I have two Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-10-zzz with identical M471B5773CHS-CK0 and sticking two identical rams each of which 2GB is NOT working :)

Comment: @hassanalrehamy So using 2GB of the PC3L or using the PC3 does not work? What happens at the boot and what does it say?

Comment: I used 2 pc3l not working, then I used 2 pc3 also not working. By not working I mean the laptop will not boot